# Dividing by number of rows as matched by ID

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a sum within a view that is calculated based on another column divided by the number of rows that match the ID. 
Example:
Total = Table.1 / (ROWS Where ID = The Same)

The view so far is:

```
Create View testview AS (
  SELECT t2.ID,t1.Sum1 FROM
  Table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN
  Table2 t2
  ON
  t1.ID = t2.ID
);
```

Below is a table example:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| T2.ID | T1.Sum1 | Total  |
+-------+---------+--------+
|     1 | 10.00   | 10.00  |
|     2 | 15.00   | 15.00  |
|     3 | 20.00   | 10.00  |
|     3 | 20.00   | 10.00  |
|     4 | 30.00   | 10.00  |
|     4 | 30.00   | 10.00  |
|     4 | 30.00   | 10.00  |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `Aggregate count` with `Window function` to get count of `sum1` in each `ID` and use it to divide the `sum1`

```
CREATE TABLE #sum
  (
     ID   INT,
     Sum1 NUMERIC(4, 2)
  )

INSERT #sum
VALUES (1,10.00 ),
       (2,15.00 ),
       (3,20.00 ),
       (3,20.00 ),
       (4,30.00 ),
       (4,30.00 ),
       (4,30.00 )

SELECT *,
       Sum1 / Count(id)
                OVER (
                  partition BY id) AS Total
FROM   #sum
```

**View** should be something like this.

```
CREATE VIEW testview
AS
  (SELECT t2.ID,
          t1.Sum1,
          t1.Sum1 / Count(t2.id)OVER (partition BY id) AS Total
   FROM   Table1 t1
          LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
                 ON t1.ID = t2.ID);
```